# How to reconfigure log4j of a war file from another war file deployed in same tomcat

Tags: java, logging, war, log4j

I have two war files WARA and WARB deployed in a tomcat, both use same log4j properties file. How to reset the log4j configurations in both war files through another stand alone application deployed in same tomcat without disturbing WARA and WARB? Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

If polling is an option you can use `PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch()`.

More **[here](http://janvanbesien.blogspot.in/2010/02/reload-log4j-configuration-in-tomcat.html)**.

If you need to do it manually the process is bit longer. On a high level its as follows.

1. Configure JMX for your application server / servlet container.
2. Write an MBean to trigger full reconfiguration.
3. Register the MBean in WARA and WARB.
4. Connect to the MBean server from the other webapp.
5. Invoke the MBean in WARA and WARB.

If you can provide more details on what software stack your are using I may be able to provide specific details on how to do the above.

Comment: Thanks.. I will try to implement this method.

Answer (score 0):

not the best way , but make a jar file that contains properties file ,and place it tomcat lib folder ,all applications use same propertyfiles.